# What is the easiest way of calculating Fermi surface averages numerically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, computational-physics, superconductivity

I am interested in calculating Fermi surface averages, which are defined as
$$
\langle X(\mathbf{k})\rangle = \frac{1}{N_F}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\delta[\epsilon(\mathbf{k})]X(\mathbf{k}),\quad N_F=\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\delta[\epsilon(\mathbf{k})],
$$
where $\epsilon(\mathbf{k})$ is the Fermion free energy minus the chemical potential $\mu$. In a trivial system
$$
\epsilon(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{\hbar^2\mathbf{k}^2}{2m} - \mu,
$$
such that the Fermi surface becomes spherical, however I'm interested in how you would calculate $\langle X(\mathbf{k})\rangle$ for a general form of the dispersion relation, which I assume has to be done numerically. I just can't for the life of me wrap my head around how to express this in a way where one could use numerical techniques to calculate it. What would be the right numerical algorithm to perform this integration?

### What I have done so far

Parameterizing the surface in spherical coordinates we can in general write the momentum sum as
$$
\langle X(\mathbf{k})\rangle = \frac{1}{N_F}\frac{V}{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^\pi\mathrm{d}\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi\;k^2\sin\theta\frac{X(\mathbf{k})}{|\hat{k}\cdot\nabla_\mathbf{k}\epsilon(\mathbf{k})|},
$$
however this requires that I can find $k_F = k(\theta,\phi)$ such that $\epsilon(k_F, \theta, \phi) = 0$, which means I have to invert this relation somehow. I have also assumed that the Fermi velocity never vanishes in the radial direction which I guess isn't always the case.